# version 1.4.2_03 of the jvm is not suitable for this product. 1.5 or greater is required problem

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jvm

Today i installed windows xp 2002 service pack2, eclipse was working fine on previous same window but now when i run eclipse it gives **"version 1.4.2_03 is not suitable for this product.1.5 or greater is required"** message and does not run. For checking my version of jvm, i visited java.com and clicked upon free java download button, it verified that i am having recommended java installed(1.6.0_27-ea) but eclipse is giving above mentioned message.Kindly tell me that what should i do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Go to the directory where eclipse is installed and find a file called `eclipse.ini`. Open it and add the following lines

> -vm
>   C:\Java\JDK\1.5\bin\javaw.exe

Make sure:

1. You add that text before any `-vmargs` option that may be in that file.
2. The `-vm` is on its own line and the path to *javaw.exe* is on its own line.
3. You specify the full path to your JDK 1.5's *javaw.exe*

Comment: ok i solved it. It should have been as follows: -vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/javaw.exe

Comment: forward slash rather than a backward slash

Answer (score 4):

1. Try to uninstall previous Java version (if it is present)
2. Find and replace with newer version the 'java.exe' binary, located somewhere on C:\Java\JDK\1.5\bin\javaw.exe

Answer (score 2):

below answer is suitable for springsuite

-vm

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_12\bin\javaw.exe

in

springsuite also same

Go to installed STS.ini
For example

F:\springsource\sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\STS.ini open in editplus keep  two lines before -vmargs as

-vm

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_12\bin\javaw.exe

it works sucessfully i had done it.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `echo %JAVA_HOME%`. And make sure that it points to your new java version.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with java 1.5 when i installed 1.6. Removed 1.5 by deleting jdk and then installed 1.6 and set java_home which solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the same, after having started Eclipse only once with Java 7 and then wanting to go back using Java 6.

Solution: In **eclipse.ini** I restored the **value "1.6"** for what was "-**Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion**=1.7".

HTH!

Answer (score -1):

Follow below stepts that will resolve problem for sure.

1) Install latest version of jdk

2) Open eclipse.ini file in editplus (search for that file in eclipse folder)

3) write first two lines like below with your java path and your java version

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_12\bin\javaw.exe

after writing that two lines your eclipse.ini files looks like this

-vm

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_12\bin\javaw.exe

-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.0.v20100503
-product
.
.
.
.
.
```