# Installing jdk of higher version

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [version 1.4.2_03 of the jvm is not suitable for this product. 1.5 or greater is required problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502399/version-1-4-2-03-of-the-jvm-is-not-suitable-for-this-product-1-5-or-greater-is)

I have installed eclipse 
But when i try to open up ...
i get an error Version 1.4.2_03 of JVM is not suitable for this product . version 1.5 or greater is required

Although i have jdk1.6.0_06 and jre6 in my computer

Please suggest a remedy

Comment: Do you also have JDK 1.4 installed on your computer? Seems like Eclipse is finding it on startup.

Comment: See @technoholic911 answer below. Of course, if your not actually using JDK 1.4 anymore you should uninstall it. I mean, that JDK is ***old***.

Comment: The question is how to get the eclipse started so the answer cannot be start your Eclipse and do x, y, z things. The answer is to tweak the eclipse launch configuration.

Comment: Check ur installed JRE's and configure it as required for the project settings.
This can be done through preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want eclipse to use other then default (for running the IDE), you have two options:

- command line argument: `eclipse -vm $JDK_HOME\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll` (you can use `clinet` too, but sever is better for eclipse case
- or to specify the same thing in the eclipse.ini

Note that, for the projects (in eclipse) you can still use other runtime configured in `Prefs->Java->Jre`

Answer (score 1):

Or you could change preferences of complete eclipse instead of single project from:

Window > Prefrences > Java > Installed JREs

Click "Add" and select correct jdk source folder.

Comment: i use Windows7 please suggest me a path to preferences

Comment: The problem is with the launch of eclipse, this can help only when eclipse is correctly starting up.

Comment: I mean while in eclipse, Goto Windows > Pref > Java > Installed JREs

Comment: Please dload a new copy of eclipse and try. It seems your eclipse is corrupted. It will be much easy configuring a new eclipse as it seems you do not have any old projects in existing eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the jdk using eclipse's -vm option like `eclipse -vm <path to jdk>`

Answer (score 0):

you need to change to JDK version in your eclipse then you will not get such errors. Follow, following steps for it,

Right Click on your Project & select Properties.

Then from the left section Select Java Compiler & select the Version of the JDK you installed. If it is already selected then de-select it & try it.

Answer (score 0):

Yoyu can change your eclipse.ini file to point to the correct java version. This link http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F offers some details although it might be outdated.

Refer to this [How do I set the eclipse.ini -vm option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905611/how-do-i-set-eclipse-ini-vm-option) for more details.